# Word for a man who still acts like a child

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a one-word term to describe a man who still acts like a child or immature?

For example:

> Steve just laughed at the word "shuttlecock". He's such a *{man who acts like a child}*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the word for an adult who is not mature?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169676/what-is-the-word-for-an-adult-who-is-not-mature)

Comment: What is "a one-word description to sum up" -- not "a one-letter word", surely?

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the term ["man-child"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/man-child) used a lot in this context. Not sure if hyphenated still meets your single word request though

Comment: It would be great if you could add some references to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks you have answered the question yourself.

The world **[Childlike](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/childlike)** fits your description